# How to set the focus on a text box?

Tags: vba, ms-access, setfocus

In one database form code generates a new record:

```
Me.Section(0).Visible = True
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Me!ExhibitName.SetFocus
```

The focus is not set on the data textbox `ExhibitName`. The focus is nowhere to be seen.

In another database, the same code (except the text box is `DistributorName`) does set the focus on the proper data entry box.

In the one that fails, if I enter `Forms!ExhibitForm!ExhibitName.setfocus<Enter>` in the Immediate window the focus goes to the proper data entry text box.

If I trap on the instruction after the `Me!Exhibit.SetFocus` and execute the `Me!ExhibitName.setfocus<Enter>` command in the immediate window, then continue execution, the focus is correct.

It feels like some indeterminate delay is needed between the 2nd and 3rd command in the above sequence. Either that or I failed to set some control somewhere.

Comment: Try to add a `DoEvents` before using `SetFocus`. Maybe that helps, if it's a kind of timing/refresh problem.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is moving the focus to another control and then back to the first control. Like this:

```
DoStuff
Me.Section(0).Visible = True
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Me.anotherControl.SetFocus
Me.ExhibitName.SetFocus
```

Answer (score 1):

This did not work:

- Me!anotherControl.SetFocus
- Me!ExhibitName.SetFocus

This did work:

- DoEvents
- Me!ExhibitName.SetFocus

Thanks!

Comment: For me it was setting focus to another control first that solved the problem...